# Using SQL Server, is there a way to query (555) 344-2524 using 5553442524?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2000

Using the PHP SQLSRV driver to connect to SQL Server 2000, is there a way I could match all of these rows using this piece of data: **5553442524**?

```
555-344-2524
(555) 344-2524
555.344.2524
1-555-344-2524
```

I imagine this would be done through a specific query probably using a stored procedure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SQL 2000 the only way I can think of would be using the `REPLACE` function.

```
declare @SearchTerm bigint

Set @SearchTerm = 5553442524

Select * From dbo.Table 
Where Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Col1,'-',''), '(',''),')',''),'.','')
= @SearchTerm
```

The problem with this would be it wouldn't cater for the leading 1.

A better way would be wrap all this logic [in to a function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

e.g.

```
Create Function dbo.fn_FormatTelephoneNumber(@input varchar(100))
returns bigint
as begin


declare @temp bigint

Set @temp = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(@input ,'-',''), '(',''),')',''),'.','')

If Len(@temp) = 11
begin
Set @temp = Right(@temp, 10)
end

return @temp

End
```

To call the function you would use it like so:

```
Select *,
      dbo.fn_FormatTelephoneNumber(YourColumnName) as [FormattedTelephoneNumber]
From dbo.YourTable
```

Or to use it in a `WHERE` clause:

```
Select *
From dbo.YourTable
Where dbo.fn_FormatTelephoneNumber(YourColumnName) = 5553442524
```

Obviously the best thing here would be to clean up the data that is stored in the columns and restrict any further "bad" data from being inserted.  Although in my experience that is easier said than done.

Comment: I'd like to be able to clean the data coming inbound, but as you said, easier said then done as the data is coming from over a hundred websites and would need to be readjusted in every instance.

Comment: @TonyMancini You could add a trigger to the table to pass the data through the function before saving it to the database. That would clean the data for you. However, you would have to ensure that your function accounted for all possibilities to prevent a failure. I would also do some testing regarding performance before implementing in production.

Comment: I seem to be running into an error while trying to run the query; `SELECT * FROM crm_main AS E, dbo.fn_FormatTelephoneNumber('5553442524') AS EID WHERE E.phone = EID.phone` - I'm getting Invalid object name 'dbo.fn_FormatTelephoneNumber'.

Comment: Put the function call in your WHERE criteria, it's not returning a table object to be joined to.

Comment: @TonyMancini See my edits on how to call the function in your queries.